# expanding the body of a page using css

Tags: css

I'm trying to expand the body of my page to the right to make some content fit. is there a way to make my content fit automatically, else if I can get some help with just expanding the body manualy is fine. Thanks.

Here is my css code:

```
html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
body {
width: 100%; height: 100%; 
margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 10em;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: 13px; line-height: 15px;
background: #EEE4B9;
}
```

Comment: using `width` as opposed to `min-width` creates problems with automatically expanding. You could try `min-width:100%;` so that it can expand over 100%. You should be able to keep the `html {width:100%;}` but then change it to `body { min-width:100%;}`. I'm not too terribly sure if it'll work, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting up your body to be the full width of your screen like this

```
html, body
{
    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    /* Set up positioning */
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;   
    border: 10em;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 13px; line-height: 15px;
    background: #EEE4B9;
}
```

Will look something like this example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use margin-right: #px;  place this and choose a value, make sure this code goes inside your body in the Css.  This will make a scroll bar appear at the bottom thought.  Or you could, if this is text lower the font size down until it fits.

Comment: Why not just provide an example?

Comment: Remove the body width 100% this is not needed anymore instead add this.

Comment: Body { background-color: green; margin-right: 10px; max-width: 100%; }